# Elements of the quotient group looks like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

[image]

What will G bar look like ? I mean element wise ?

Comment: How do the elements of $G$ look like? Then start from there.

Comment: No no..I mean, in x,y representation, I have got it, but in representation of elements ? I mean the ordered pair of  integers ? Maybe it's a silly question to ask, but i am confused. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So $G=\mathbb{Z}_4\times\mathbb{Z}_4$. Write it down as

$$G=\{(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),$$
$$(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),$$
$$(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),$$
$$(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3)\}$$

Your generators are $x=(1,0)$ and $y=(0,1)$. The subgroup generated by $x^2y^2$ is

$$H=\langle x^2y^2\rangle=\{(0,0), (2,2)\}$$

And so the quotient is

$$G/H=\{\overline{(0,0)}, \overline{(0,1)}, \overline{(0,2)}, \overline{(0,3)},$$
$$\overline{(1,0)}, \overline{(1,1)}, \overline{(1,2)}, \overline{(1,3)}\}$$

Note that for example $\overline{(2,0)}=\overline{(0,2)}$ is already included on the list. That's because $(2,0)=(0,2)+(2,2)$ and so they generate the same coset.

Comment: Thank you... This is what I needed.